# Jest test failure with React component

Tags: reactjs, browserify, jestjs

I am trying to test a react component, here is the test

```
jest.dontMock('../js/components/Navigation.js');
var React = require('react/addons');
var Navigation = require('../js/components/Navigation.js');
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var Route = require('react-router').Route;
var Link = require('react-router').Link;
TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;

describe('Navigation', function() {

 var NavElement = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
    <Navigation items={['nav1', 'nav2', 'nav3']} />
  );

  var items = TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(NavElement, 'li');


  it('renders each item as a li', function() {
    expect(items.length).toEqual(3);


  });


});
```

Here is the component

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var Link = require('react-router').Link;
var RouteHandler = require('react-router').RouteHandler;    

var Navigation = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
            <header>
            <ul>
            <li><Link to="nav1">nav1</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="nav2">nav2</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="nav3">nav3</Link></li>
            </ul>
            </header>
            <RouteHandler />
            </div>
            );
        }
    });
```

When I run 'npm test' I get the following arning and error
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).

```
  - Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
```

What am I missing?

I tried removing and resintsalling node modules
Also tried importing as

```
var Navigation = require('../js/components/Navigation.js').default;
```

And using

```
modules.export = Navigation;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your component have

```
module.exports = App;
```

part?

Looks like you might have not imported it properly

You also need to import `Link` and `RouteHandler` components inside the component file, right under where you import React.

Comment: Still getting the same error after adding it. Just to clarify , I added it end of file

Comment: Ok now just make sure you include it like this: `var Navigation = require('../js/components/Navigation.js');`

Comment: It is errorring out for the render method of Navigation component

Comment: You also need to import `Link` and `RouteHandler` components inside the component file, right under where you import React. Updated my answer.

Comment: Route handler is imported wrong. `var RouteHandler = require('react-router').RouteHandler;  `

Comment: Thank you, i changed it but still have the same error

Comment: Can you `console.log('Navigation', Navigation);` from the test just to verify it's loaded ok? You also don’t need .js in require

Comment: I tried logging it and its 'undefined', I had removed the .js in my import

Comment: Fixed it, I imported the component inside the describe method!

Comment: Yes Thank you! modules.export was also needed for it to work!